# Optimizing a complex list comprehension statement

Tags: python, list, algorithm, performance, list-comprehension

**How can I optimize the list comprehension statement in `Step 3`?**

Background:

In the real world:

- `r` contains about ~500 elements and
- `a` contains about ~1 million elements

Please note that `Step 3` is a nested loop over both `r` and `a`. Hence, it takes a lot of time. In the below code `r` and `a` are shortened for simplicity.

I am also mentioning this function, `some_heavy_calculation()`, for background purposes. This function is not revealed here, but since it also is called `len(r) * len(a)` times, it also consumes a lot of time.

In an effort to speed things up, I have noticed that I can avoid 90-95 % of all calls to `some_heavy_calculation()` by introducing the "faster" alternative. The only problem is that `Step 3` now takes a lot of time. In fact, this step consumes more time than I am able to save.

```
def some_heavy_calculation(rules, data) -> list:
    # ...
    return []

# r = input rules
r =  ['x', 'y', 'z']

# a = input data
a =  [7,     7,     7,     4,     4,     2,     2,     8,     2,     9,     4,     4,     8,     7    ]

#########
# Slow alternative: b = result of some_heavy_calculation(r, a)
# b = expected result, size: [ r x a ]
b = [[True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  False, True,  True,  True,  True],
     [True,  True,  True,  False, False, True,  True,  True,  True,  False, False, False, True,  True],
     [False, False, False, True,  True,  False, False, True,  False, False, True,  True,  True,  False]]
#########

#########
# Faster:
# Since these steps avoids 90-95 % of all the calls to some_heavy_calculation()
#
# Step 1: c = a in order, but without duplicates
c =  [7,                   4,            2,            8,            9                                ] 

# Step 2: d = result of calculation, size: [ r x c ]
d = [[True,                True,         True,         True,         False                            ],
     [True,                False,        True,         True,         False                            ],
     [False,               True,         False,        True,         False                            ]]

# Step 3: e = should equal b
e = [[d[ri][next(ci for ci, cv in enumerate(c) if cv == av)] for ai, av in enumerate(a)] for ri, rv in enumerate(r)]
#########

str(b) == str(e) # <--- returns True
```

Comment: Is that list comprehension just a way to look up correct the elements from `d` that correspond to the elements of `r` and `a`?

Comment: Yes, exactly only that

Comment: The `ai` value from `for ai, av in enumerate(a)` is not used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that what you need is a pattern called [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization).

There is a [`functools.cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.cache) decorator (for Python < 3.9 you can use [`lru_cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache)) that you can use this way:

```
import functools

@functools.cache
def some_heavy_calculation_per_item(rules, value) -> bool:
    # ...
    return []

def some_heavy_calculation(rules, data) -> list:
    # ...
    returned = []
    for value in data:
        returned.append(some_heavy_calculation_per_item(rules, value))

    return returned
```

Using memoization is effectively doing the calculations once per each value (the savings of 90-95% as you noted) but also in a memory efficient way (no need to combine many large lists or arrays).

Another potential optimization is to use `yield` instead of constructing the list in `some_heavy_calculation` function but this depends on the way you consume the result - if value by value then `yield`ing will improve performance. If you need the list in its entirety - then it won't help at all.

Comment: Wow. Nice. I have not heard about that at all.

Comment: Does that work even if the some_heavy_calculation() is performed in parallell. I am using with Pool(processes=8) and pool.map(partial(some_function, ...), rules) where some_function() in turn applies the some_heavy_calculation().

Comment: Yes, each process should construct a separate cache so there may be some duplication (you have to check it, in the worst case - initialize cached functions individually per each process).. However, you can be smart about sending the same values to the same processes - just send the value to a process of `id = number % 8` (`%` is modulo) - and the use of caching will be efficient as well as result calculated once.